# Sum the value of array elements with the previous element(s)

Tags: javascript

I need a hand to **sum** the value of array **elements** with the previous element(s) and return a new array.

So if we have :

```
let durations = [4, 3.5, 6];
```

then in the new array the **first element** is 4, the **second element** would be the sum of `4 + 3.5` and the **third one** would be  `4 + 3.5 + 6`; so the desired result would be `[4, 7.5, 13.5]`

So far it seems that reduce unexpectedly just concat the numbers and returns an array of strings !!!

```js
let durations = [4, 3.5, 6];
let arr = [];

let durationsNew = durations.reduce((a, b) => {
    arr.push(a + b);
    return arr;
}, []);

console.log(durationsNew); // The desired result is [4, 7.5, 13.5]
```

Comment: In the first Iteration when you doing `a + b` its actually `[] + b`, the values in the array converted to `string` because of the plus sign

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you take the accumulator `a` and add the value to it. The accumulator is an array and this is converted to string by using it with a plus operator.

---

Instead, you could take a variable for sum and map the sum by adding the value for each element.

```js
let durations = [4, 3.5, 6],
    sum = 0,
    array = durations.map(value => sum += value)

console.log(array); // [4, 7.5, 13.5]
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than mine using Array.reduce. In benchmark test Array.map runs slightly slower than reduce.

Comment: i think, the main problem is not speed, but to understand what `reduce` is doing with the parameters.

Comment: Probably true. I found Array.reduce to be confusing when I first started using it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use reduce, you have to do something like this:

```
let durations = [4, 3.5, 6]

let durationsNew = durations.reduce((_durationsNew, duration, durationIndex) => {
    if(durationIndex > 0) {
      _durationsNew.push(_durationsNew[durationIndex - 1] + duration)
    } else {
      _durationsNew.push(duration)
    }
    return _durationsNew;
}, [])

console.log(durationsNew); // The desired result is [4, 7.5, 13.5]
```

Example: https://repl.it/repls/HandsomeVacantRate
Benchmark test with Array.map, Array.reduce, and for loop: [image: Benchmark test withi Array.map, Array.reduce, and for loop.]

Answer (score 1):

Try this - a mixture of `map()` and `reduce()`:

```
[4, 3.5, 6].map((num, i, arr) =>
    num + arr.slice(0, i).reduce((a, b) =>
        a + b, 0)); //[4, 7.5, 13.5]
```

The idea is to map the array to a new array, and for each number, the new number returned is the number + the sum of the array values up to that number.